# how I can use identityserver4 from my php app

Tags: php, swagger, identityserver4

I need to use latest news from fiba website and they provided an [swagger API](https://bbm-api.fiba.com/swagger) which using identityserver4 for authorization system

Our application is PHP and I tried to find something related to php and identityserver but I could not.

I want to send a request to identity server from php and get a access token from that.  How can I do this?

Comment: The authorization seems to be done with OAuth2 - identity server is just the application, which provides the interface for OAuth. If you google for PHP and OAuth, there should be more than enough resources in libraries

Comment: Maybe this is useful https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a token you can use (it works on my installation):

```
curl -d "client_id=<YOURCLIENT>&client_secret=<YOURCLIENTSECRET>&grant_type=password&username=<youruser>&password=<topsecretpassword>&scope=default openid" -X POST http://youtidentityserver4.tld/oauth/connect/token
```

Then you will get something like:

```json
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUz....long token",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

As next you can use following request to fetch user information:

```
curl -i http://youtidentityserver4.tld/oauth/connect/userinfo \
-H "scope: default openid" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUz....long token"
```

After executing this you should get something like:

```
{
    "sub": "j2h4kh42k4242jhg4j2hg42k34gb2k"
}
```

depends of your user-database configured behind your IdentityServer4.

**sub** =  short for “subject” => a unique identifier for the user

Use the same scopes on /token request that you want to use later at /userinfo.
Otherwise you will get an error "insufficient_scope":

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2018 15:52:40 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
WwwAuthentication: Bearer
WwwAuthentication: error="insufficient_scope"
```

If you need more scopes look under http://youtidentityserver4.tld/oauth/.well-known/openid-configuration and look there under "scopes_supported". (replace youtidentityserver4.tld with your domain)

To realize all this in PHP use some of the well known clients like [curl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) directly or [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).